# How am I supposed to make a button link to another html file in chrome-devtools?

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I am a student who is making an app for my group's STEAM Tank project. I can't figure out how to make a button link go to another HTML file in chrome-dev tools. I am working in an index.html file to make the title page. This is the code I have:

```
<img src="2icon_128.png" alt="Tardy Time logo" width="400" id="tardy-time-logo">
<h1 id="tardy-time-heading">Tardy Time</h1>
<h2 class="tardy-time-slogan"><strong><em>If you can't beat Tardy Time, Join Tardy Time</em></strong></h2>

<div class="header">
    <span class="title-btn"><a target="_blank" href="file:///home/chronos/u-e6b8f2a6cde1e9636abef34ef65d593e08bdd9e8/MyFiles/Downloads/Tardy-Time-App/beginning.html" class="title-btn">Let's Start</a></span>

</div>
```

I need to get to a file called beginning.html, which is located inside the same folder, "Tardy-Time-App". The error I am getting is the not allowed to load local resource error. I am working in chrome devtools.

Comment: have u tried by writing in the `a` tag as this `href="./beginning.html"` or only `href="beginning.html"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is you're in the **same folder** just pass the name of your file like this:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="beginning.html" class="title-btn">Let's Start</a>
```

So you don't need to pass the absolute path of your file

Comment: I have, it does not work. It does not do anything, it just stays there on the first page.

Comment: The second page of the app is the beginning.html file